# Qt Form UI greyed out

Tags: qt, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator

When I enter the ui design page, and press <kbd>F4</kbd>, all of components will grey out.

What happened and how to fix it?

[image: UI greyed out]

I could only solved this problem by restarting Qt Creator.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F4</kbd> opens [signals/slots editing mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-connection-mode.html#connecting-objects), press <kbd>F3</kbd> to go back to [widget editing mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-widget-mode.html#editing-a-form).

Qt Designer shortcuts are different from Qt Creator's.